# Possibility to create QAction as a separator in constructor

Tags: qt4, pyqt4, qaction

I have dozens of `QAction` objects creating in the constructor of widget without giving them variable names.

Many of properties of `QAction` can be set right in the constructor (e.g. `shortcut`, signals connections, `statusTip`, etc.).

Is it possible to set `QAction` as a separator right in constructor and how to do it?

P.S. I think it's not a language-specific question but FYI here's what I'm using:

**Python** 2.7.6; **PyQt4** 4.10.3; **Qt** 4.8.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: No.

PyQt's [support for properties](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qt_properties.html) only allows you to set Qt-defined properties in the constructor. A quick skim of the [properties section for QAction](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html#properties) confirms that there is no `separator` property, so you cannot set it in that way.

Of course, there is a very simple and obvious workaround for this. Just define your own subclass of QAction, and do the necessary configuration in its `__init__`:

```
class Action(QtGui.QAction):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Action, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setSeparator(kwargs.get('separator', False))
```

Comment: Thank you. I've forgot to check QT documentation - only PyQt4.